# HTML/CSS specify border-color in first DIV

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can not manage this situation:

```
 <div class="list">
    <div class="bar">
       <header></header>
       <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <header></header>
       <div class="content"></div>  //select this
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <header></header>
       <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.list > .item:first-child .content {
   border-color: red;
}
```

I tried many solutions:

1. `.list > .item:nth-of-type(1) .content { border-color: red; }`
2. `.list > div.item:first-child .content { border-color: red; }`
3. `.list .item:first-child .content { border-color: red; }`

but no any result.

Comment: You cannot. Because you don't have an `item` class in the first `div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick note.** The [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector selects only tags for now.

> The `:nth-of-type()` CSS pseudo-class matches elements of a given type, based on their position among a group of siblings.

If I understand correctly, you are looking for this:

```css
.list > div:nth-of-type(2) .content {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="bar">
    <header>Head</header>
    <div class="content">
      Content 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <header>Head</header>
    <div class="content">
      Content 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <header>Head</header>
    <div class="content">
      Content 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On a different note, you need to set the `border-width` and `border-style` to make sure the border is displayed.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mircea You are welcome! `:D`